# time complexity unsorted backtraching array

Tags: java, time-complexity

so i've got an assignment where there is this method:

public int backtrackingSearch(int[] arr, int x, int fd, int bk, Stack myStack)
That receives an unsorted array of integers arr and searches for the index of the first
occurrence of the value x with the added property that after every fd many search
steps, backtracks bk many steps back. The
algorithm stops if it finds the needed index or reaches the and of the array.

now i've been asked about the time complexity when calling for the function with (A, x, 1, 2) - for . ℎ > 1 > 2 ≥ 0.

I really have a hard time to analysis the time complexity here

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's try to find the time complexity without trying to find the runtime function.
In order to do that, we should examine the worst possible case. In this example, the worst case is when x does not exist in the array. So the program will iterate through the entire array.

But the program also has to backtrack every n1 steps forward, which makes the process slower. Every time we try to check new elements, we also backtrack n2 elements backward, to a place where there are no new elements for us to check.

So the question is, how much do these additional "rules" affect our original n steps through the entire array (when n is the size of the array)? Do we spend additional n steps for each element? - leading to the complexity of O(n²). Or is it linear? - which means that our original n steps are only multiplied or added to constant numbers that don't depend on the size of the array.

Well, the additional steps only depend on the values of n1 and n2, right? If the size of the array is doubled, we expect the runtime to double as well. So when the size increases, the runtime should increase linearly.

Therefore, the time complexity of this method is O(n) - linear.